# Angular, using variable for timer in setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, settimeout

If I use a number directly for `setTimeout(() =>{}, 300000)` a setTimeout will fire after 5 min. However if I use a global variable it fires immediately:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  timeoutCounter = 300000;

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() { this.fireMe(); }

  fireMe() {
    setTimeout(() =>{}, this.timeoutCounter);
  }
}
```

In theory it should fire the same way but the setTimeout fires like I've provided no value at all.

Comment: perhaps because it s undefined hence the "immediate execution" can you try and assign value to you variable inside the contructor?

Comment: @EugenSunic that's what I assume but... why? I need to have a global var to set some other timeouts. Having to set the value for each would make code upkeep a pain.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. The code above works as expected for me.

Comment: so what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

just define a new function called getTimeOut() with whatever limit you want and call that method using 'this' inside your class.

it's not working because you hadn't called any function inside setTimeout(),
setTimeout usually takes two args, the function and a timestamp.
setTimeout(function(), timestamp)

Comment: Makes sense! Can you provide a code example to help illustrate?